# Url friendly htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I've been working in make urls in my siteweb more user friendly:
So I've been modifying the htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^diseno-grafico/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ diseno-grafico-filtro?id=$1&rubro=$2

RewriteRule ^diseno-web/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ diseno-web-filtro?id=$1&rubro=$2

RewriteRule ^ilustracion/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ ilustracion-filtro?id=$1&rubro=$2

RewriteRule ^arte/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ arte-filtro?id=$1&rubro=$2

RewriteRule ^animacion/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ animacion-filtro?id=$1&rubro=$2 

RewriteRule ^proyectos/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ proyectos-filtro?id=$1&rubro=$2

RewriteRule ^ilustracion/galeria-clasica/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ galeria-clasica?id=$1&rubro=$2
```

so urls are cleaner more easy to read:
https://ugocd.com/diseno-grafico/Accordion-Brochure/diseno_grafico
[https://ugocd.com/diseno-web/UI,-SEO-y-Maquetaci%C3%B3n-HTML-CSS3/diseno_web](https://ugocd.com/proyectos/Serie-Animada-EnnuComic-Animado/proyectos)
https://ugocd.com/ilustracion/Ilustracion-en-tintas/ilustracion

What I would like now and I dont know how to do it is to dont show the last part of the url diseno_grafico, diseno_web, ilustracion, etc because Is repetitive dont five anything usefull.

Can somebody please help me? I think I'm preaty close

I've tried using this?:
`RewriteRule ^arte/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ arte-filtro?id=$1&rubro=$2 [QSA]`

And this, but it doesnt send the variable **rubro**, I dont want to show it in the url but I want it to still send it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/diseno_web$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it appears like you simply want to specify that second group in a literal way so that you do not have to specify it a second time in the requested URL.

Which leaves us with something like that which would rewrite requested URLs like `https://example.com/diseno-grafico/Accordion-Brochure` as expected:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^diseno-grafico/([^/]+)/?$ diseno-grafico-filtro?id=$1&rubro=diseno-grafico [L]
```

This obviously only works for "specialized" rules covering exactly one such term. *Maybe* you can generalize that like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1-filtro?id=$2&rubro=$1 [L]
```

You might have to add a whitelist though to prevent that rule from getting applied to requested URLs that you do *not* want to get rewritten:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(diseno-grafico|diseno-web|ilustracion)/([^/]+)/?$ $1-filtro?id=$2&rubro=$1 [L]
```

Or using a condition:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(diseno-grafico|diseno-web|ilustracion)/
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1-filtro?id=$2&rubro=$1 [L]
```

Or maybe such a variant to enhance readability:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/diseno-grafico/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/diseno-web/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ilustracion/
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1-filtro?id=$2&rubro=$1 [L]
```

---

I decided to ignore that last example you gave. That requested URL has a different pattern. Handling such differences certainly is possible, but it makes the implementation much more complex, so harder to maintain. I assume that last example is a mistake in the question since you nowhere mention that exception in your description.

A straight forward approach for handling such patterns would be that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(?:.+/)?([\w-]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1-filtro?id=$2&rubro=$1 [L]
```

It ignores everything and including a first slash, anchoring that matching pattern to the end of the requested URL.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and time to answer. I've applied your solution but it gives me a 500 Internal Server Error.

I'm starting to think It could be the configuration of my APACHE? that limitates some rules?

Comment: It might well be that I made a typo somewhere. Sorry for that, but I obviously did not _test_ that with an actual server. You will have to check your http server's error log file. Which _always_ is the first thing you should do with such issues. That is the place where the server explicitly says into what issue it ran.

Comment: Ah, this _might_ be an endless rewriting loop of you used the first, most simple form of the generalized approach. Have a try using the `[END]` flag instead of the `[L]` flag or add an explicit condition that prevents the application of the rule if the URL ends on "-filtro".

Comment: Thank you for your time, still does not work, I have this error IN THE DEV TOOL CHROME : 

JOB:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

https://ugocd.com/diseno-grafico/JOB

I've tried to activate error logs in my server hosting but still I dont see it with detail.

I've use this code:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^diseno-grafico/([^/]+)/?$ diseno-grafico-filtro?id=$1&rubro=diseno_grafico [END]

I tried with END also but didnt work.
the word in the end is "diseno_grafico" not "diseno-grafico" so the other codes are not working for that I guess.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the difference between hyphen and underscore, thought that was a typo too. You _could_ add a replacement for that, but that again adds complexity which is why I would not recommend it. Sounds like separate, specialized rules for each such category is the way to go.

Comment: The 404 is something I cannot help with I am afraid. This contradicts what you said before, though, where you said you received a 500. So what is it?

Comment: yes the 500 is when I used : RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/diseno-grafico/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/diseno-web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ilustracion/
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1-filtro?id=$2&rubro=$1 [L] the other where at least I am be able to see the NoT Foun page is where I use: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^diseno-grafico/([^/]+)/?$ diseno-grafico-filtro?id=$1&rubro=diseno_grafico [L]

Comment: I think Im gonna give up, guess nothing I can do for now. but thank you for your time.

Comment: Don't give up, certainly that is possible.

Comment: For the first attempt where you get a 500 I am afraid you will need to check in the log files. There was one mistake in my answer for that variant with the multiple conditions, they need to be connected with an `[OR]` flag which I added above (sorry for that!). But that does not explain the http status 500.

Comment: For the second variant producing the 404: most likely the rule does not get applied, that would explain the 404. I fail to see the reason for that, though.